# how to dynamically set the url in Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android

I am using Universal Image Loader that I found [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). In this case, the url of the images is set statically or preset in `String[] IMAGES`. What I wanted is to make it more dynamic, say it is coming from the URL. (`http://site.com/myfile.xml`). I am done with parsing the XML but now my problem is setting it in Constant class in `UIL`. Is there any way to set the IMAGES dynamically? am I in the right direction? (parsing the `xml` and saving it in the `ArrayList` and convert it in to `String[]` array.)

Comment: After parsing the xml using a asynchronous task in post execute you can convert the array list to string array then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

After parsing the xml, in `getView()` of your adapter use `ArrayList.get(position)` instead of `String[position]`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and this is how I accomplished it :

I have one Async task which get the urls of the images from a url . So essentially it return me JSON string with list of urls. Once that request is complete , I have a listener which notifies my Fragment to update the List view.

The Async task returns a list of strings which I add to list being used by the adapter.

//Code in Async task

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            if (null != mClient)
                mClient.close();
            //TODO
                //Constants.IMAGES = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
            Constants.IMAGES.addAll(result);
                Log.i("IMAGES", IMAGES.toString());
                if (mTheListener != null && firstCallFlag ) {
                    firstCallFlag = false;
                    mTheListener.GotoNextScreen();
                }else{
                dataUpdateListener.dataUpdated(result);
            }
        }
```

//Code in the fargment

```
public void dataUpdated(List<String> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imageUrls.addAll(data);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```